# EC2 instance launch log deny IAM Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I need to give read only access for AWS services. There is a read only built in policy in IAM. This overall work fine. But user can see EC2 launch logs (EC2 > Instance settings > Get System Logs). Here user can see ssh keys. So is there any way we can restrict this as well? any EC2 get system logs deny policy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Remove the `GetConsoleOutput` permission from the user permission or deny this specific permission for the users.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": "ec2:GetConsoleOutput",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

[instance-console-console-output](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output)